# Upgrading to premium subscription from standard in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, subscription

Do we loose data which is stored in Hive storage DBFS in databricks, when upgraded to Premium Subscription from standard subscription in Azure Databricks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/account#--upgrade-or-downgrade-an-azure-databricks-workspace)

> Notebooks, users, and cluster configurations are retained when you upgrade or downgrade a workspace, but active clusters might be terminated.

When I reproduced your query, my data in **Hive storage DBFS was not affected** after upgrading the subscription from **standard to premium**.

[image]

Therefore, **we don’t lose the data stored in the Hive storage DBFS** in azure Databricks, when upgraded to premium subscription from standard.

To **upgrade or downgrade the Azure Databricks workspace**, please go through this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/account#azure-portal).

Comment: Man, Thanks a lot, really appreciate your efforts of answering, Thanks